# How Might Nearby Re-Radiators Affect the Radiation Patterns of a Transmit Antenna?

Tags: radiation-pattern

Here is one example of such, based on a NEC study...

Answer (score 2):

The NEC4.2 study/graphic first below shows how a structure comprised of conductors to (roughly) emulate the a-c power lines in a wood-frame house might affect the radiation patterns of a 40m-band vertical monopole located six feet away from one side of that house.

The effects of this may be different than those expected. 
[image]

**Below are the patterns for that monopole and its buried ground rod, by themselves (other things equal).**

[image]

**Added on 2 Feb 2018:  This may be drifting too far off the original topic, but  the affect of even relatively tall structures with steel frames on the FAR FIELDS of a transmit antenna can be negligible, as long as the dimensions of the structure are small enough in terms of wavelength.**

**Below is a graphic showing the measured relative fields of an AM broadcast station on both sides of a path from a distant transmit antenna toward, and past such a structure.** *RJF*

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to also see the pattern of the antenna without the "house", for the sake of comparison.

Comment: OK, I added them to the original post.

Comment: So the "house" changes the best takeoff angle quite a bit, to be nearly vertical rather than 25° or 30°.  I wouldn't have expected such a large effect, but perhaps that makes sense given that a lot of the RF is being absorbed and re-radiated.  The azimuth pattern is distorted also, which is less of a surprise.  Very interesting!